# Automatically resizing two elements together to match the browser

Tags: html, css

Unsure how to explain this properly.

I have two elements on my web page that I need to properly align and resize together to match the browser.

The image isn't the current problem, but I have a second element that I cannot get to properly match and resize.

So, the top of my website will have an image that automatically sizes using this CSS code:

```
.top { 
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-inxed:0;}
```

I need another element placed over top of that, covering part of the first image.

Since it will not let me post an image here, which would explain much better than just trying to describe by words, I have posted in here:

As you can see, I want to put the time box I have generated through javascript over the time from the top bar. When the browser resizes, I need it to maintain the position and size with the top image.

I have tried nesting it inside a div, but it seems it will not resize properly.

As per request, here is the code I currently am using:
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="UbuntuDesktop">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/master/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/time.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery("#responsive_headline").fitText();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div><img class="top" src="Graphics\Ubuntu_Desktop_top_bar.png" />
<div id="udclock"><span id=curTime></span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    #UbuntuDesktop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background-image: url("Ubuntu_Desktop_12_04.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


.top { 
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-inxed:0;
}

#udtopwrapper {
}

#udclock {
    background-color: #4c4b47;
position:relative;
top:0;
right-margin:20px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I don't think the js code will help. It is one that I found that will show the current time, and I am creating a dynamically changing time.

Comment: consider using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Please post your markup — and creating a [minimal, concrete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help tremendously.

Comment: Posted. My HTML is not very long. I am just learning, but could not find an answer anywhere. Basically, I want the .js clock to overlap where the top bar clock would be in Ubuntu, and to match the browser size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssQ1.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <p>Text here</p>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}

header{background-image:url('download\ \(1\).jpeg'); 
    height:100vh; 
    background-position:center; 
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;}

p{color:white;
    font-size: 200%;}
```